# Error during execution of cron job in subfolder application made in Yii 1.1

Tags: yii, cron

I have following code written for webApi it works when running manually.

```
    public function actionProcesspush()
{
    $date = 'Today is '.date("D M d, Y G:i", time());
    echo $date;
    // the message
    $msg = $date."First okok line of text\nSecond line of text";

    // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

   // send email
  if(@mail("me@swapnil.tech", "My Test New Cron ok ok", $msg))
  {
     echo "Mail Sent Successfully okokok";
  }else{
  echo "Mail Not Sent";
  }
}
```

This code is working if i put it in Cron Job for main site. But When i copy My system in sub folder inside public_html, code is running manually. But Cron execution is not done. I copied application in "testingnoundersore" folder inside public_html.
The error log gives following error.

```
thrown in /home/takeawayjunkies/public_html/yiiframework/web/CWebApplication.php on line 286
[11-Feb-2018 06:11:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "testingnoundersore/mobileapp/cron/processpush".' in /home/takeawayswapnil/public_html/yiiframework/web/CWebApplication.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 /home/takeawayswapnil/public_html/yiiframework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('testingnounders...')
#1 /home/takeawayswapnil/public_html/yiiframework/base/CApplication.php(185): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 /home/takeawayswapnil/public_html/index.php(50): CApplication->run()
```

Comment: My htaccess for main site
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://takeawayjunkies.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: My htaccess for testing site is
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testingnoundersore/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /testingnoundersore/index.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://takeawayjunkies.com/testingnoundersore$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/how-to-run-a-cron-job
As Cron Jobs set on VPS are given different than sharing hosting.

normal curl command

```
curl "https://www.takeawayswapnil.com/test_environment/merchantapp/cron/processpush"
```

for VPS

```
curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron "https://www.takeawayswapnil.com/test_environment/merchantapp/cron/processpush"
```